# Merge Multipart Feature Line

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-database, geometry, network, merge

I'd try to merge multipart feature line, but didn't work.
would you please teach me how to merge multipart feature line?

I work in version environmental and geometry network.

Regards,

Comment: Welcome Adityayuda, What software are you using to apply the merge?

Comment: Ooh sorry, i'm using arcgis 10.0.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe the steps leading up to the error.  Thanks.

Comment: And provide the error message. "Didn't work" does not help us to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create multipart features, you can use the [Dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000) tool. You can use attributes to define how features will be grouped (feature with the same attribute(s) will be grouped). If you don't select any attributes, all line features will be merged into one single multipart.
You can also merge features manually in an edit session: select all the lines you want to merge and click the Merge option in the Editor menu.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For PostGIS and SpatiaLite use [ST_LineMerge](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_LineMerge.html) (in Oracle Spatial it is something similar like ST_LineMerger).  ST_LineMerge is different to a simple union operation in that it does not consider the order of the vertices (as stored in the database) but returns a linestring where the lines are joined topologically.  This avoids unwanted jumping back and forth.  ST_LineMerge returns a multilinestring if there is a discontinuity in the linestrings you give it.

The Shapely Python API has something similar: [shapely.ops.linemerge(lines)](http://toblerity.github.io/shapely/manual.html)

Comment: honestly, i don't have python basic, so i can't understand how it works. can you teach me step by step?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Multiparti To Singlepart" tool in ArcToolbox under Data Management Tools then in the Features Toolset